# How to fix receiving UDP data on windows?

Tags: networking, python, wireshark, udp

On a windows 10 machine I am running the following python code (3.10.11) to receive data on UDP port 9001 (without any VM running):

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 9001))
sock.settimeout(5)

while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    decoded = json.loads(data.decode())
    print(f"received message:  {decoded}")
```

However, I run into a `TimeoutError`.

When checking with `wireshark` I can see these data being received every second on port 9001, and when I start a Ubuntu VirtualMachine on the same Windows machine and **run the exact same code** I can read the UDP data on port 9001.

So how to make it work so the python code runs on windows directly?

Do I have to set some permissions? Is windows unable to handle UDP packets? Is this a firewall issue? What is going on? How to fix it so the exact same python code works on windows?

Comment: Have you *tried* adding a firewall rule to allow incoming data on this port? (Usually the built-in Windows Firewall would've shown a prompt for python.exe as a whole; the same rules list would show whether you had allowed or blocked it in the past.)

Comment: I am not very familiar with firewall rules. I see there are like 15(?) rules for python, but I have no idea what they are about or what the differences are ... But I changed to allow them all (no idea what I am doing) but now it seems to work!!

Comment: Most of them I suspect relate to the specific .exe's (e.g. you probably have one for python3.10.exe, one for python3.9.exe, etc?) – open `wf.msc` if you're not using that already (this is the full rule editor) and take a look at each rule's properties. It'll list the executable or the ports.

Comment: How are you running this code - as its own executable?